# How to use jQuery to traverse json data object

Tags: jquery, xml, json

From a ajax response, I got a object as below --

```
"highlighting":{
    "http://example.com/test1":{
        "content":["sample content 1"],
        "title":["sample title1"]},
        "http://example.com/test2":{
            "content":["sample content2"],
            "title":["sample title1"]
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please let me know how to get the "http://example.com/test*"? I could loop for "content", "title", but "http://example.com/test*" because there is not a name associated with.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because that string is a key, and not a value. When you iterate the object, supply an index and you'll be able to fetch it.

Comment: That would actually be the first key ?

Comment: you may burn me for it, but you should consider restructuring your response if you are able.  put the url in the object with its own key.  it will ease your navigation of the object significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the keys in Question.. Try this

```
var data = obj["highlighting"]
for( key in data ){

    alert(key)
}
​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UUUGW/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"highlighting":{//first key
                           "http://example.com/test1": { //first key in first key
                               "content":["sample content 1"],
                               "title"  :["sample title1"]
                                                       },
                           "http://example.com/test2":{ //second key in first key
                               "content":["sample content2"],
                               "title":["sample title1"]
                                                      }
                          }
          }

var first;
for (var i in obj.highlighting) {
    first = obj[i];
    break;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BTthv/)